# ios 13 background task morethan 30 second not working

Tags: ios, api, background-process

> How to run background task more than 30 seconds?

When Network api call is running and application going to background so it working till 30 seconds.

If Network api call response get after 30 seconds it will not catch by application on background mode.

I am implemented **BGProcessingTaskRequest** and it is working for 30 seconds.

Anybody have a idea how to increase background task time to 45-60 seconds **because sometime Network api call take 40 to 50 seconds**.

Comment: May be you should use background fetch instead of background tasks

Comment: I'm also using background fetch but not working on iOS 13

Comment: Apple resolved the issue to prevent apps from downloading content in the background.
Please check in ios  13.2.3,  it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Facing the same issue with background task..

Comment: @BhaumikSurani any solution so far?

Comment: @Nitesh No, currently it's 30 Seconds